# Real time log and result method

Tags: c#, class, logging

I've created a method execution result class in C# that can include a Boolean success result, as well as an execution log message.

I wanted to modify this class so that, in the case of a long or tedious method, the message information would not be sent at the end all at once, but in real time as it was received, so that it could then be retrieved by the GUI and displayed in a log window.

But I don't quite understand why, for example, if I call the log update as follows:

```
result.UpdateLog("CP");
result.UpdateLog("Test");
```

My result in the log window will be

```
CP
CP
Test
CP
Test
```

Here is my result class

```
public class Result
{

    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public StringBuilder Message { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess => Success;
    public event Action<string> LogUpdated;

    public Result()
    {
        Success = false;
        Message = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void UpdateLog(string message)
    {
        Message.AppendLine(message);
        OnLogUpdated(Message.ToString());
    }

    protected virtual void OnLogUpdated(string updatedLog)
    {
        LogUpdated?.Invoke(updatedLog);
    }
}
```

My GUI method

```
private void UpdateTextBoxLog(string updatedLog)
{
    tb_log.Text += updatedLog;
}
```

Initialization with log update event and method call

```
Result result = new Result();
result.LogUpdated += UpdateTextBoxLog
MyMethod(param1,param2,result)
```

My Method

```
...
result.UpdateLog("CP");
result.UpdateLog("Test");
connection.Connect(cmServerName);
result.UpdateLog("Connection OK");
result.Success = true;
```

I would expect each log info to be displayed once, but no, the first ones are displayed several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public void UpdateLog(string message)
{
    Message.AppendLine(message);
    OnLogUpdated(Message.ToString());
}
```

You're passing the entire StringBuilder output every time, after appending the message.

Rather, you should simply pass `message`:

```
public void UpdateLog(string message)
{
    Message.AppendLine(message);
    OnLogUpdated(message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I had my nose in it for a while but couldn't see anything :)
Ah, finally something that makes sense!